# Two sums out of a product

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, summation, products, data-analysis

#### Problem

Assuming $\theta \in [0, 1], y_i \in \{0, 1\}$, 
I'm having trouble deriving the expression on the right from the one on the left:
$$
\begin{align}
\prod_i \theta^{y_i}(1-\theta)^{(1-y_i)} ~~~~~\Longrightarrow~~~~~ \theta\sum_i y_i(1-\theta) \sum_i (1-y_i)
\end{align}
$$

The meaning is that $\theta$ is the probability of heads in a coin toss and $y_1$ is an outcome (a head or a tail).

#### Attempt

I thought I'd start by taking the log of the product:

$$
\begin{align}
\prod_i \theta^{y_i}(1-\theta)^{(1-y_i)} &= \exp\log\bigg(\prod_i \theta^{y_i}(1-\theta)^{(1-y_i)}\bigg)\\
&= \exp\sum_i \bigg(\log\theta^{y_i} +\log(1-\theta)^{(1-y_i)}\bigg)\\
&= \exp\sum_i \bigg(y_i\log\theta^{} +{(1-y_i)\log(1-\theta)}\bigg)\\
\end{align}
$$

Stuck at this point. Any feedback appreciated.

Source: Kruschke (2014) *Doing Bayesian Data Analysis*, 2nd Edition, formula 5.11:

[image]

Comment: I am confused . did you mean $\prod_i \theta^{y_i}(1-\theta)^{(1-y_i)}$ so $ \theta^{\sum y_i}(1-\theta)^{\sum (1-y_i)}$?

Comment: @Masoud Added a photo of the formula from the book, but I don't think so, everything appears unexponentiated.

Comment: @Masoud Ah, now that I see your answer and the last line with theta^heads, I see it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\prod_i \theta^{y_i} (1-\theta)^{(1-y_i)}= \theta^{ y_1} \theta^{ y_2} \cdots \theta^{ y_n }(1-\theta)^{ (1-y_1)} (1-\theta)^{ (1-y_2)} \cdots (1-\theta)^{(1-y_n)}
$$
$$=\theta^{ \sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i } (1-\theta)^{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (1-y_i)}$$

$$=\theta^{ \sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i } (1-\theta)^{n-\sum_{i=1}^{n} -y_i}$$

$$=\theta^{ heads } (1-\theta)^{n-heads}$$